# gtrends package giving "not enough search volume error"

Tags: python, r, variables, gtrendsr

Whenever is run this, i get a "not enough search volume error". Can someone explain me the reason for this? The term in demo[1] is "Neoforma.com Inc"

```
library(gtrendsR)
require("XLConnect")


library(readxl)

# read_excel reads both xls and xlsx files

data <- read_excel("mydata.xlsx")

listnames <- list(namesonly)
len<-length(namesonly)

ch <- gconnect("xxx@gmail.com", "xxxx")
for(i in 1:len){
  print(demo[i])
  lang_trend <- gtrends(query=demo[i]**strong text**)
  #jpeg(file= c("data number", i , ".jpeg"))
  plot(lang_trend)
  #dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems like there are potentially ongoing problems with `GtrendsR`, take a look at the GitHub - it suggests installing the dev version, but this corrupted for me. There was some suggestion that the 'volume' issue was due to hitting the API limit, but clearly this isn't the case. Sorry to not be more help.

> Changes in Google Trends API
>
> Due to recent changes to Google Trends API, the CRAN version of the package is no longer working. If you wan to continue to query Google Trends, you have to install the development version of the package. This will be soon deployed on CRAN.